# getting a subset of an array with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

In Matlab it is quite easy to get a subset of an array/matrix. I want to get that using VBA, without writing a lot of loops.

I am not good with VBA. I read a couple of articles on this subject and came to the code below. However, I am still falling short. The details of the problem are in the code.

```
Sub subsetArray()

    Dim MyArray() As Double
    Dim output1, output2 As Double
    Dim i, j, startRow, endRow As Integer
    startRow = 1
    endRow = 3
    ReDim MyArray(1 To 5, 1 To 3)

    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 3
        MyArray(i, j) = i + j * 2
        Next j
    Next i
    'this one works
    output1 = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Index(MyArray, 4, Evaluate("ROW(2:3)")))
    'the below does not work. I want to do average on the 1st column, the first two elements..i.e first 2 rows
    'output2 = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Index(MyArray, Evaluate("ROW(1:2)"), 1))

    ' last problem is that I also want to use a variable to state the start and end row
    ' example is below
    'output2 = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Index(MyArray, Evaluate("ROW(startRow:endRow)"), 1))

    MsgBox (output1)
    'MsgBox (output2)
    Erase MyArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather frustrating this, you have to use `Application` rather than `WorksheetFunction`.

`output2 = WorksheetFunction.Average(Application.Index(MyArray, Evaluate("ROW(1:2)"), 1))`

For your variables, just use standard concatenation approach

`output2 = WorksheetFunction.Average(Application.Index(MyArray, Evaluate("ROW(" & startRow & ":" & endRow & ")"), 1))`

I'll see if I can find something on this, I used to have a useful link which I can't currently find.

---

By the way `Dim output1, output2 As Double` declares `output1 as Variant`. You need `Dim output1 As Double, output2 As Double`.

Comment: Thanks everyone,,,, appreciated